# create script to convert array to string with array elements uniquely with randomness

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python script that generates random rows with a provided array. To better explain

```
input : [1,2,3,4,5]
output :
[1,2,3,4,5]
[5,3,4,2,1]
[1,2,4,5,3]
[1,2,5,3,4]
[5,4,3,2,1]
[4,3,2,1,5]
```

I am sharing the function which generates the unique random placement of item in array for now

```
def myscore(self):
    # setting the values which I want in my output array
    score_array = array.array('i',[0,1,2,3,4])
    score_index_len = len(score_array)
    score_string = ''
    loopidx=0
  
    while loopidx < score_index_len:
        #generate random index between number of array item  
        i=randint(0,len(score_array)-1)
        score_string = score_string + ',' + str(score_array[i])
        #remove the index
        del score_array[i]
        loopidx = loopidx + 1 
    return score_string[1:]
```

Please share your code review comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performance

Since [f-strings are faster than string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38722105/9997212), you can replace

```py
score_string = score_string + ',' + str(score_array.pop(i))
```

with

```
score_string = score_string + f',{score_array.pop(i)}'
```

---

Since [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) removes an element from a list given an index and returns it, you can simplify

```py
score_string = score_string + ',' + str(score_array[i])
del score_array[i]
```

to

```py
score_string = score_string + ',' + str(score_array.pop(i))
```

### Best practices

Since [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) creates a iterable once in the iteration, you can replace

```py
loopidx = 0
score_index_len = len(score_array)

while loopidx < score_index_len:
    ...

    loopidx = loopidx + 1
```

with

```py
for loopidx in range(len(score_array)):
    ...
```

---

Since [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) is an alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`, you can simplify

```py
i = randint(0, len(score_array)-1)
```

to

```py
i = randrange(len(score_array))
```

---

Just for readability, you could replace

```py
score_string = score_string + f',{score_array.pop(i)}'
```

with

```py
score_string += f',{score_array.pop(i)}'
```

---

To avoid using `[1:]` when returning, you could create a new list and use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```py
scores = []
for loopidx in range(len(score_array)):
    i = randrange(len(score_array))
    scores.append(f'{score_array.pop(i)}')
    
return ','.join(scores)
```

#### Refactored code:

```py
def myscore():
    score_array = array.array('i',[0,1,2,3,4])
    
    scores = []
    for loopidx in range(len(score_array)):
        i = randrange(len(score_array))
        scores.append(f'{score_array.pop(i)}')

    return ','.join(scores)
```

### Alternative

A simpler alternative is just use [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
def myscore():
    score_array = array.array('i',[0,1,2,3,4])
    shuffle(score_array)
    return ','.join(map(str, score_array))
```

Comment: I would argue that if you need the index out of each iteration you should use enumerate as its more idiomatic: